# How to make "Permanently store this exception" checkbox active?

Tags: firefox, certificate

I'm trying to connect to a website which uses a self-signed certificate. Firefox tells me that my connection is not secure and on clicking *Advanced* button I can find *Add Exception...* button, clicking which I get a dialog, where I can confirm the security exception. But the checkbox *Permanently store this exception* is grayed out, so I'm unable to store it permanently.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The option which disables the ability to store security exceptions appears to be *Never remember history*. You can find it in *Options*->*Privacy*->*History*. Once you switch it to *Remember history* and restart Firefox, you can permanently store the security exception. If you then switch that option back, the exception will remain stored, so you can enable this feature back after adding the exception.

Comment: My default installation had 'Remember History' as the selected option, but the option to permanently store the exception was still grayed out.  I had to change to 'Never Remember', restart, and then change it back before the security dialog allowed me to permanently store it.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed answer from @sdanna.  I had to allow "Remember History" temporarily, set the permanent checkbox on my desired site exceptions one by one and then switch it back to "Use Custom Settings."  Worked perfectly after that.